# Why does QGIS / MMQGIS / Geocoding always show a connection error to Google Maps although I want to use Nominatim?

Tags: qgis, geocoding, nominatim, mmqgis

I am currently trying to geocode addresses from a CSV file using QGIS (2.18.22) via MMQGIS (2018.1.2) and the Nominatim Geocoder.

[image]

Unfortunately there is always a strange error.

[image]

Why does Nominatim try to contact the Google Maps API? How do I solve this problem?

Comment: I tested the MMQGIS OSM/Nominatom geocoder in QGIS 3.4, and got this error message: `Request denied: 0 addresses geocoded.` No mention of google api, so it's unclear if that's the same issue or not. You can make a bug report here: https://github.com/michaelminn/mmqgis/issues.

Comment: As per the [help/on-topic] it is OK to try and reproduce software problems in a Q&A here, but if you think this is a bug then be sure to submit it to the plugin developer. Please post a link to the bug report here.